# Points on a circumference

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems with getting all points (integers) on a circumference.

This is my current code:

```
function getPixelsInRect(x, y, width, height) {
   var result = [];

   for (var i = y; i < y + height; i++) {
       for (var j = x; j < x + width; j++) {
           result.push([ j, i ]);
       }
   }

   return result;
}

function getPixelsOnCircle(x, y, radius) {
  return getPixelsInRect(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius *    2).filter(function(pixel) {
    return Math.pow(pixel[0] - x, 2) + Math.pow(pixel[1] - y, 2) == (radius * radius);
  });
}
```

It filters out all points that are not on a circumference. It's obviously not working as it should and I'm sure it's not the right approach. Any suggestions?

(Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/852Loubf/)

Comment: What do you mean by "obviously not working"? It seems to print points on a circle for me.

Comment: Because a circumference of a circle includes a lots of points that are not integers and I need all the points, like when drawn on a canvas.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/852Loubf/1/)? Your `getPixelsInRect` does return only integers, so you cannot expect `filter` to get you the non-integer points on the circumference.

Comment: You will want to have a read on [the midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Comment: I was thinking about the midpoint circle algorithm, but couldn't quickly wrap my head around it. I'll need a longer read then.

Comment: You need "all" points on the circumference?

Comment: @Cerbrus well, there are infinity of them :P I need only integer ones.

Comment: Right, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mh I think it's because you compare the distance with the `radius` the too stricly

I made some changes to take a threshold into account, you can play with the new parameter `threshold`, which is kind of a thickness. Below 1 it won't be a continuous line. ([fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/852Loubf/4/))

```
function getPixelsOnCircle(x, y, radius, threshold) {
    threshold = threshold === undefined ? 1 : threshold;

    return getPixelsInRect(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2).filter(function(pixel) {
        var rectDist = Math.pow(pixel[0] - x, 2) + Math.pow(pixel[1] - y, 2);
        var rectDistSmoothed = Math.round(rectDist / radius);

        return  rectDistSmoothed <= radius && rectDistSmoothed >= radius - threshold;
    });
}
```

Your `drawPoints` function also needs to be fixed:

```
points.forEach(function(point) {
    ctx.fillRect(point[0] - 0.5, point[1] - 0.5, 1, 1);
});
```

And `getPixelsInRect`:

```
for (var i = y; i <= y + height; i++) {
    for (var j = x; j <= x + width; j++) {
        result.push([ j, i ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried it earlier, but the "thickness" must be `1` in my case and then it's not working as it should (leaving the bottom and bottom-right part "stripped").

Comment: Oh yeah forgot that, it's because you draw rects with a top left origin, updating my answer

Comment: Ok, the "clipping" problem is in `getPixelsInRect` function. I think it's working.